# percentage value in column gives Nan and infinity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to calculate percentage row wise and result gives NAN or infinity in some cases .

the result shows NAN or infinity in column to calculate the percentage

```
 <Column    editable={false}    value={  ((this.state.someRow1!== null  &&` 
 this.state.someRow1!== 0 )&& (this.state.someRow2!== null &&`  
 this.state.someRow2!== 0)) ? (this.state.someRow1* 100) / 
 this.state.someRow2`
  : "" }
```

0 or actual percentage

Comment: what's with the `\`` characters on three of those lines?

Comment: ccopy mistake but its &&..thanks

Comment: if `this.state.someRow2` is `"0"` for example, or `""` then you'll get Infinity ... if this.state.someRow1 is `""`, you'll get NaN ... check the **type** of value in someRow1 and someRow2 - or change all occurences of `this.state.someRow?` to `+this.state.someRow?`

Answer (score 0):

Coerce the values to numbers - which makes the code simpler too, since `+null === 0` - (as does `+""`) you'll only need to check against `0` for each "someRow"

```
<Column    editable={false}    value={  
        ( !isNaN(this.state.someRow1) &&
          !isNaN(this.state.someRow2) &&
          +this.state.someRow1!== 0 && 
          +this.state.someRow2!== 0) ?
        +this.state.someRow1 * 100 / +this.state.someRow2: "" 
    }
```

Comment: really? what are the exact types and values of `this.state.someRow1` and `this.state.someRow2` ? They must be non-empty strings, or objects or undefined or something